# How to upgrade kubernetes repos on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, apt

I have two Kubernetes clusters, one on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (first) and another on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (second). Both of them are using Kubernetes 1.26.10.

I try to upgrade both to version 1.27.x, but first's apt cannot find 1.27-packages.
first shows:

```
apt-cache madison kubeadm
kubeadm | 1.26.11-1.1 | https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb  Packages
kubeadm | 1.26.10-1.1 | https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb  Packages
kubeadm | 1.26.9-1.1 | https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb  Packages
kubeadm | 1.26.8-1.1 | https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb  Packages
kubeadm | 1.26.7-1.1 | https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb  Packages
```

and repos:

```
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb/ /
```

second:

```
apt-cache madison kubeadm
kubeadm |  1.28.2-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm |  1.28.1-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm |  1.28.0-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm |  1.27.6-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm |  1.27.5-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm |  1.27.4-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm |  1.27.3-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm |  1.27.2-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm |  1.27.1-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm |  1.27.0-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm | 1.26.11-1.1 | https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb  Packages
kubeadm | 1.26.10-1.1 | https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb  Packages
kubeadm | 1.26.9-1.1 | https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb  Packages
kubeadm |  1.26.9-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm | 1.26.8-1.1 | https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb  Packages
kubeadm |  1.26.8-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
kubeadm | 1.26.7-1.1 | https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb  Packages
kubeadm |  1.26.7-00 | http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

and repos:

```
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
deb http://europe-north1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb/ /
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
```

Maybe something to do with second's
`deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main`
But if I remove it, both can see 1.26 after that.
[Official Kubernetes upgrade-document](https://v1-27.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/change-package-repository/#verifying-if-the-kubernetes-package-repositories-are-used) says, that 1.27 should be available on on
`https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.26/deb/`

Comment: I tried replicating this issue but everything worked well for me. Seems the apt source list which you having now is not updated for a while and is outdated. Since I'm working with the latest apt source list I'm able to find all the packages. Can you verify when your list got updated last time..? this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410247/) will be useful for you in finding when you list got updated last time and if it's not updated for a while try running apt-get update command.

Comment: I have checked apt update & apt upgrade weekly to be sure, what has been updated. Now done just before trying to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation you are linking](https://v1-27.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/change-package-repository/#verifying-if-the-kubernetes-package-repositories-are-used) to again.

Quote from it:

> 2. Change the version in the URL to the next available minor release, for example:
>
>    ```
>    deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.27/deb/ /
>    ```

---

Side notes:

- You should remove the `apt.kubernetes.io` repo.

  > The legacy package repositories (apt.kubernetes.io and yum.kubernetes.io) have been deprecated and frozen starting from September 13, 2023.
- Kubernetes v1.27 is already outdated as well.

Comment: Yep, you are right - good point! 
I have only read this from document. Document is for 1.27
> You're using the Kubernetes package repositories and this guide applies to you